# SetVisibleMapRect always goes to arctic ocean

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

I am using monotouch to develop an app for the IPhone that needs to be able to locate a place on a mapView to zoom in on. SetVisibleMapRect seems to be the right method but I always end up in the middle of the arctic ocean no matter what values I pass in. Am I doing something wrong or am I just using the wrong method for what I am trying to do?

```
map.SetVisibleMapRect(new MKMapRect(new MKMapPoint(39.0044444, -76.8758333), new MKMapSize(1000,1000)), true);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `SetVisibleMapRect` method takes an `MKMapRect` which uses `MKMapPoint` units.  These are not the same as latitude, longitude, and meters.

You probably want to use the `SetRegion` method instead and create an `MKCoordinateRegion` using the [`FromDistance`](http://docs.go-mono.com/MonoTouch.MapKit.MKCoordinateRegion.FromDistance%20%28MonoTouch.CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2D,%20double,%20double%29) method.